# SalesForce - Is there a way to download all fields from a "contacts" list without admin privileges?

Tags: python, excel, bash, web-scraping, salesforce

**Basic Situation**

I currently have access to a salesforce page that has a 5000+ list of contacts. However, the page can only be loaded 25 contacts at a time and copying and pasting is unfeasible. Clicking a contact also gives other useful details but the general list is the most important. I don't have access to an admin portal; I only have viewing access to specific content such as contacts.

The link is structured as follows: https://example.force.com/example/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?offset=25&fpg=1cjmlvhdxsqly&str=epsilon-mu&sen=&fen=003&initialViewMode=detail&relatedListId=Contact&aId=_1527023282480&cookieParam=cookieParam1527023882485&tyme=1527023282485

**My View**

[image: view1]

**Question**

Is there a method (such as python, bash script, url edit, web-scraping, etc.) to either download the list (as a .cvs or .txt) or make the list populate in its entirety for simple copy and paste?

Comment: I tried editing the url field for "initialViewMode=" to equal "summary" but that just makes a list that cannot be expanded with a "Show More" button amended. There error in the console is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyPrefix' of undefined at b.successCallBackDrilldown......" etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get the whole table into Excel I run this script. You will need to add in your login details and the table name.

```
import csv
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce


"""
Downloading the table
"""
# Logging in to SF and creating object
sf = Salesforce(
    password='{{password}}', username='{{uName}}', 
    security_token='{{token}}',
    client_id='TestingApp')

# Getting the field names
tableInfo = sf.{{tableName}}.describe()
tableFields = []
for x in tableInfo['fields']:
    tableFields.append(x['name'])
hdrs = ', '.join(tableFields)

output = sf.query_all("SELECT " + hdrs + " FROM {{tableName}}")

headline = []
for key in output['records'][0]:
    headline.append(key)


with open('C:\\temp\\Table.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = headline)
    writer.writeheader()
    for record in output['records']:
        writer.writerow(record)
```